# What IP's should the servers be assigned?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, vlan

I have got 4 subnets (calculated using online calculators)

The major network is: 172.16.0.0/16

The students subnet having the highest IP requirement /22 mask gets 172.16.0.1 - 172.16.3.254 as assignable IP's

Staff subnet /23 mask gets 172.16.4.1 - 172.16.5.254 as assignable IP's

Management subnet /27 mask gets 172.16.6.1 - 172.16.6.30 as assignable IP's

Servers subnet /27 mask gets 172.16.6.33 - 172.16.6.62 as assignable IP's

Should I follow this IP addressing scheme or should the servers get the first 30 IP's of the network i.e. 172.16.0.1 - 172.16.0.31 ?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of space to allocate in 172.16. 
Why not make use of it and create larger subnets? Less risk of crowding in the future and easier address plans if all networks are at least /24 large.

Answer (score 1):

One point for using 172. rather than 10 or 192.168.

10 points off, for, having opted for the less usual major range, using the default bottom of it.

You have 172.16 through 172.31 available. Show 172.17 or 172.19 or 172.22 (etc) some love. You'll thank yourself later if you ever need to do anything with VPNs. Really.

I agree with Mattias that going smaller than /24 is downright silly in private address space. I'll also suggest that you plan for at least 10 times the addresses you think you might ever need. It's much easier to have absurd amounts of space preassigned than it is to go through and renumber everything. Been there, done that, they were all out of t-shirts so I didn't get one. My observed use at this point in time is upwards of 4 addresses per user as devices proliferate.

So, a suggested alternate scheme might be: 172.19.0.0

172.19.0.1 - 172.19.15.254 (/20) for your students.

172.19.18.1 - 172.19.18.254 (/24) for servers

172.19.19.1 - 172.19.19.254 (/24) for management

172.19.24.1 - 172.19.31.254 (/21) for staff.

Where you put stuff does not matter so much as documenting where you put stuff, preferably to the point that you are not required to decipher it, whether you win the lottery or get hit by a truck.

Comment: I will be using VPN connection too, so can you explain why 172.17, 172.19 or 172.22 will be helpful while using VPN?

Comment: Because it's less likely that the place your clients are connecting from will be using that - when the place you are VPN-ing in from and your place use the same private IP space, things don't work right, since they don't know which 172.16.0.1 (say) they are connecting to - the local one or the one across the VPN. By using a less-common part of the Private IP range, you reduce the odds of that happening.

Comment: Im currently a networking student, therefore my knowledge isn't quite good.  Thanks for the explanation, it was really helpful.